# Data export import module node id different after imported

Tags: importing-exporting

I using [Data export import module](https://www.drupal.org/project/data_export_import) in my new Drupal 7.

I imported Drupal 6 database into Drupal 7 site.

But unfortunately the node id for the same article is different.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [UUID](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid) module, some quote from module page :

> This module provides an API for adding universally unique identifiers
>   (UUID) to Drupal objects, most notably entities. Features in Drupal 7
>   version Automatic UUID generation
>
> UUIDs will be generated for all core entities. An API is provided for
>   other modules to enable support for custom entities. UUID API for
>   entities, properties and fields
>
> With this unified API you can load entities with entity_uuid_load() so
>   that all supported properties and fields are made with UUID
>   references. You can also save entities formatted this way with
>   entity_uuid_save() (depends on Entity API). Export entities to use as
>   default/demo content
>
> The integration with Features module provides the ability to export
>   UUID enabled entities with intact dependencies and references to other
>   entities. This functionality depends on Deploy module 7.x-2.0-alpha1
>   (soon to be released) and is probably the most robust way for
>   installation profiles and distributions to provide demo content!

The problem is that Drupal uses serial ids for the content (nodes), so if we have the same site installed different places, the id for the same content most likely will be different. (fx in one environment the node id might be 137, while it on another might be 153)
This makes it very hard to track changes on the same content in different environments. The idea with UUIDs is to create a id that is the same on all environments.

Comment: Is this module installed in Drupal 6 or Drupal7? Or both have to? @zhilevan

Comment: @JasonJason in both

Comment: @JasonJason you're welcome